# CMake miss QT_DEFINITIONS variable for Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

CMake have special variable ${QT_DEFINITIONS} for Qt4 which contains qt defines such as QT_NO_DEBUG and QT_DEBUG. There is no such option for Qt5.

How can I add standard Qt5 defines in cmake?

Answer (score 1):

Please check `<component>_DEFINITIONS` / `<component>_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`.

There's an example using Qt Widgets and CMake [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/cmake-manual.html#module-variables). The two essential parts:

```
# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

# Add the include directories for the Qt 5 Widgets module to
# the compile lines.
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Calling `find_package()` will set those variables for you:

- **`Qt5Widgets_VERSION_STRING`**
- **`Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES`** List of libraries for use with the `target_link_libraries` command, for example.
- **`Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS`** List of libraries for use with the `include_directories` command, for example.
- **`Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS`** List of definitions for use with `add_definitions`, for example.
- **`Qt5Widgets_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`** List of definitions for use with the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` target property.
- **`Qt5Widgets_FOUND`** Boolean describing whether the module was found successfully.
- **`Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS`** String of flags to be used when building executables.

*(Quoted from link above; the name depends on what you search in your `find_package()` call)*

Comment: Unfortunately none of these variables have QT_NO_DEBUG.
As a workaround I will add QT_NO_DEUBG, QT_DEBUG manually.

These defies are required to make proper QtDesigner plugin.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? 2.8+? (if not, please test this version).

Comment: Thx for pointing me out on CMake bugtracker. I was using 2.8.11 and it looks like they have just released new version.